# Md5 Column function on column in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, md5

How do you call Md5 Column function on all columns in a table from spark sql?

Is it the same as HiveSQL syntax?

```
SELECT md5(*) FROM employee;
```

Answer (score 2):

Spark SQL includes the HiveContext so your statement should work.  Prior to Spark 2.0, you may need to specify the HiveContext (though the SQLContext often will do the trick.  For Spark 2.0, the Spark session includes the HiveContext so you will not need to specify it.